# Visual Studio 2019 regularly loses the ability to open Unity projects (unsupported)

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

Nothing was changed when all of a sudden Visual Studio 2019 suddenly couldn't open Unity 2019.2.4f1 projects.

[image]

[image]

Once it happened several months ago. That time it was cured by itself when I downloaded a clean Unity project from my repository. Just yesterday it happened again. I spend the whole day surfing forums and trying to fix but nothing helped until I decided to completely reinstall Visual Studio. Today everything was fine until suddenly it started again.

I didn't change anything, just was working with code.
External tools settings are set as they were.

[image]

Any ideas why it could happen and how to fix it without reinstalling VS?
Is it possible to somehow find out what exactly the VS can't understand in the project files?

Comment: Why are there 48 projects in the solution?

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know, it was given to me to work on just recently. The problem exists for any solution no matter how many projects it has.

Comment: Unity normally creates new solutions as-and-when so you don't normally track them in git/whatever.  I would delete it and get Unity to recreate it.  And stop tracking it.  However there should only be one project in there as that's all Unity needs, so something other than Unity is happening here.

Comment: I tried to delete them all and to be generated by Unity many times. It didn't help. They are not tracked by Git.

Comment: Instead of using Visual studio 2019 use Visual studio code its free and open source and unity recommend this.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2019 go to Extensions -> Manage Extensions and check that "Visual Studio 2019 Tools for Unity" extension is installed, and enabled.

Comment: Make sure you right click on the solution in the solution explorer in Visual Studio and reload all the projects.